# Fetching BasicInfo, BillingInfo, and DocumentInfo objects

Tags: python, django

The repetition is super obvious here. How can I rewrite this code? I need one base method in which I pass a Django model, to call `objects.filter`, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
from profiles.models import BasicInfo, BillingInfo, DocumentInfo

__author__ = 'vol'


class BasicInfoService:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_profile_id(profile_id, is_versioned):
        if is_versioned:
            return BasicInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')
        return BasicInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')[:1][0]


class BillingInfoService:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_profile_id(profile_id, is_versioned):
        if is_versioned:
            return BillingInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')
        return BillingInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')[:1][0]


class DocumentInfoService:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_profile_id(profile_id, is_versioned):
        if is_versioned:
            return DocumentInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')
        return DocumentInfo.objects.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')[:1][0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template method pattern seems useful here:

- Create a base class with a `get_by_profile_id` method that calls a `get_queryset` method to get the at appropriate QuerySet object to work with
- The base class doesn't implement `get_queryset`, it's the job of the subclasses. This is the template method

Something along the lines of this in the base class:

```
def get_by_profile_id(self, profile_id, is_versioned):
    queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')
    if is_versioned:
        return queryset
    return queryset[:1][0]
```

And in the subclass for `BasicInfo`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return BasicInfo.objects
```

Notice that I eliminated another duplication in the following and ordering logic. Note that Djangi will not execute the query until elements are accessed in the query set, so when I initialize `queryset` before the `if` condition, that doesn't hit the database.

Comment: Can you check out my answer, and write some comment to that? I used your idea with `get_queryset` function.

Comment: Yeah like that. I improved it a tiny bit, hope you like it (see the edit on your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using the @janos idea, I try to apply inheritance for my implementation, it looks pretty compact right know:

```
from profiles.models import BasicInfo, BillingInfo, DocumentInfo

__author__ = 'vol'

class ProfileInfoService:
    def __init__(self, provider):
        self.info_provider = provider

    def get_by_profile_id(self, profile_id, is_versioned):
        info = self.info_provider.filter(profile_id=profile_id).order_by('-version')
        if is_versioned:
            return info
        if info:
            return info[:1][0]          
        return []          


class BasicInfoService(ProfileInfoService):
    def __init__(self):
        ProfileInfoService.__init__(self, BasicInfo.objects)


class BillingInfoService(ProfileInfoService):
    def __init__(self):
        ProfileInfoService.__init__(self, BillingInfo.objects)


class DocumentInfoService(ProfileInfoService):
    def __init__(self):
        ProfileInfoService.__init__(self, DocumentInfo.objects)
```